# Can we hook custom handler on click of given bold, italic button /icon click in Google document through Google app scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I found Google app scripts very cool for extending many custom functionality. But I stuck in one case where I want to show some message on click of Bold, Italic buttons(icons) embedded in  Google document. I am able to do same thing for my custom menu items but unable to trap the events raised by already given buttons/icons.Is there any API exposed in Google Apps scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Document-contained scripts have the ability to extend the document editor UI functionality by adding menus, sidebars and dialogs.

There is no API access to the standard UI menus or buttons.